# How to compare dates and given the difference between them?

Tags: java, date

I've found out a very useful library which is the `SimpleDateFormat` for the formatting of date. That is not the problem. The `compareTo` method serve my purpose of comparing the date but my problem is that the `compareTo` doesn't show the difference between then

For example the code below:

```
    String date1 = "Apr 2010";
    String date2 = "Jan 2009";

    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM yy");

    Date d1 = null;
    Date d2 = null;
    d1 = format.parse(date1);
    d2 = format.parse(date2);

    int test1 = d1.compareTo(d2);
    System.out.println(test1);
```

The output of the above gives me `-9`. May I know how does the method `compareTo` calculates it?

What I want is that to find the difference between those months and years. Thank you very much.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Editted. Sorry, forgotten to include the format changer just now

Comment: You have to define what you mean by "difference" -- i.e. what units you want to use. Days? Months? Years?  What is the "difference" you want to get back for the two dates you give above?

Comment: @JimGarrison The difference between the months and years.

Comment: Still not enough information.  For the two dates in your example, provide _exactly_ what you want to see as the result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `compareTo` method is inherited  from `Comparable`. Its javadoc states

> Compares this object with the specified object for order. Returns a
>   negative integer, zero, or a positive integer as this object is less
>   than, equal to, or greater than the specified object.

So that is all you are going to get from `compareTo`. Just which is bigger/smaller/equal.

If you want to compare date fields, you will need to do it yourself. Or use a third party library like Joda Time. For example

```
String date1 = "Apr 2010";
String date2 = "Jan 2009";

DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("MMM yyyy");

DateTime d1 = formatter.parseDateTime(date1);
DateTime d2 = formatter.parseDateTime(date2);

Months monthsBetween = Months.monthsBetween(d1, d2);
System.out.println("Months diff: " + monthsBetween.get(DurationFieldType.months()));
Years yearsBetween = Years.yearsBetween(d1, d2);
System.out.println("Years diff: " + yearsBetween.get(DurationFieldType.years()));
```

prints

```
Months diff: -15
Years diff: -1
```

Comment: I see, I thought it would return values for the difference of dates. Thank you very much for your information.

Comment: @user3054491 You're welcome. The support for Date object is going to greatly improve in Java 8, so be on the lookout.

Comment: Oh my, Thank you for the information. You've been a great help to me !

Comment: One question, I copied and paste your code into my NetBeans but I got error on the `Month`. Is Month a library? Because NetBeans doesn't show what library to include and I'm getting the error there.

Comment: @user3054491 Yes, that's what I meant by 3rd party library. Joda Time is a library specialized in date processing. You can check out the project [here](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/). You can download the version you want [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/joda-time/files/joda-time/). You will need to add them to your Netbeans project build path.

Comment: Oh, thanks alot, you've really been a great helper here !

Answer (score 0):

Check out the Calandar class. it's used to get and set actual date properties like years, months, days etc.  here is one I wrote recently...

```
public Date addDays(Date date, int deltaDays) {
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTimeInMillis(date.getTime());
    calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, deltaDays);
    return new Date( calendar.getTimeInMillis() );
}

public Date getFirstWeekdayOfYear(int dayOfWeek, int year) {
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
    calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, 0);
    calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
    while (calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) != dayOfWeek) {
        calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
    }
    return new Date( calendar.getTimeInMillis());
}

public boolean isOlderThan(Date date, int days) {
    return date.getTime() < getToday(0-days).getTime();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make Calendars of Dates

```
Calendar c1 = Calendar.getInstance();
c1.setTime(d1);
Calendar c2 = ...
...
```

then get years and months from Calendars

```
int y1= c1.get(Calendar.YEAR);
int m1 = c1.get(Calendar.MONTH);
int y2 = 
...
```

now find the difference using integer arithmetic